# Running a UDP server using WCF?

Tags: wcf, udp, .net-4.5

I have been investigating about creating a UDP server, at first i though i would have to get a dedicated server as i want to run EXE on the server but i currently have a shared server and i believe most ports are open.

I notice that with the WCF 4.5 (pre release) you can create UDP services, would these work in the same way as a UDP server hence a client could send messages to the UDP service in the same way (i.e. UDPClient class).

I presume this is available in 4.5 only and not 4 / 3.5?

What are the pros and cons of running a UDP server vs WCF service with UDP binding?

As far as hosting the UDP WCF service, can this be done on IIS like a standard WCF HTTP service?

Or a console application is required?  Of course if a console app is required or something similar then this doesn't help me as I would still need a dedicated server to host the item. This is where i am a little confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I've read in [What’s new in WCF 4.5? UDP transport support](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/idof/archive/2012/02/15/what-s-new-in-wcf-4-5-udp-transport-support.aspx):

> The binding is not supported in IIS/WAS, since there is still no UDP shared listener for WAS

Comment: Thanks, ermm thats not good news then :-)  So my options are to host in a console app, win service etc.  So whats pros and cons are there with using the WCF udp service rather than writing a similar service using thd UDP classes?  Thanks for your reply!

Comment: @Martin: I think windows service is a good way to implement that. Later probably you will be able to switch to self-hosting WCF service bound to UDP.

Comment: @Martin: I would use FCL/WCF in maximum to minimize your own code, because it will be less error-prone, it will be more tested and reliable.